# Forbidding external domain access

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite

**Question**: I would like to allow only my website's form; `<form action="link"` to navigate to www.domain.com/link when my form is submitted. But to deny direct access to the URL www.domain.com/link.

**Attempt**: So far I know how to forbid access with mod_rewrite:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} link
RewriteRule ^.*/?link/? - [F]
```

But I do not know how to allow a form submit to access the page. I explored the possibility of using a input tag with a secret value to allow access if the form get submitted by doing this

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} link
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !secret_key
RewriteRule ^.*/?link/? - [F]
```

**Alternative**: But a user could just copy and paste that key as a query string whenever they want to access the page directly. And even if I hid the query string using mod_rewrite, a smarter user can still access the page by inspecting the input tags. What is the sure fire way to secure a page like this? Without contaminating the query string.

Comment: Could hiding a query string secret key in $_SESSION be a possibility? How would I pass a session variable as a query string, would be my next question.

Comment: ... Why would you bother with this?  No matter what you do, a smart user will be able to spoof a request that submits that form.  That's the nature of HTTP - a good request is virtually indistinguishable from a bad one.  Especially with a condition like "only from this form".  The closest thing I could come up with is to add a randomly generated `<input type="Hidden" />` to the form, and check it against some stored $_SESSION variable - but what about multiple windows? What then? Maintain an array of valid keys with expiration dates? I think you're better off assuming every request is tainted.

Comment: @SofianeM What is your problem? Why do you think, the request must come from this form?

Comment: The form action attr leads to another page. I want to make sure users cannot access this form page without filling the first form first. I know that this can be easily done with $_SESSION. But even if I use a session variable check on the second form page, the only way to redirect if it does not come from the first form is to echo the <meta> for redirect. I want to instead RewriteRule the url completely to redirect elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is not reliably doable with mod_rewrite.

Just check, if the form values are filled properly, which you must do anyway. If the values aren't filled, redirect with

```
header('Location: elsewhere.html');
```

or simply return another view instead.